# Importar csv do bucket s3

Tags: python

Estou tentando importar este um arquivo .csv do bucket S3 da Amazon
usando o código abaixo:

```
import csv
with open('https://s3.amazonaws.com/carto-1000x/data/yellow_tripdata_2016-01.csv', 'rb') as teste:
    reader = csv.reader(teste)
    for linha in reader:
        print linha
```

Estou usando  a IDE PyCharm com o Python 2.7.13 que já vem instalado no Mac. e recebo uma mensagem que o link não existe e quando chamo o link no browser ele abre tranquilamente.

Alguém sabe se preciso de alguma biblioteca para conseguir ler este  csv que esta no S3?

Lembrando que fiz um teste com um csv local e funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Quando vc faz `open('qualquer string')` o python tenta "resolver" 'qualquer string' como um arquivo local, como vc colocou uma url, o arquivo não é encontrado. Segue uma solução para ler o arquivo da url:

```
from contextlib import closing    
import csv, io, requests, urllib.request, codecs
from contextlib import closing

url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/carto-1000x/data/yellow_tripdata_2016-01.csv'

with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as data:
    reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(data.iter_lines(), 'utf-8'))
    for row in reader:
        print (row)
```

Comment: Olá Sidon.  Obrigado pela ajuda. Eu fiz do jeito abaixo e tb  funcionou (estou aprendendo rsrs  ) .O que preciso fz agora é calcular a quantidade de linhas que existem no data set e tirar a média do campo:Tip_Amount. O problema que não consigo extrair os dados e jogar em uma variável para poder calcular

Comment: url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://s3.amazonaws.com/carto-1000x/data/yellow_tripdata_2016-01.csv")
    
  reader = csv.reader(url, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        for row in reader:

x = reader.ix[:,1]
y=reader.ix[4]

#Calcular a quantidade de Linhas deste Data Set
    print("QUANTIDADE:")
    print(x.count())

#Calcular a média do Campo: Tip_Amount
    print("MÉDIA:")
    print(y.mean())

Comment: Como assim? reader já é o proprio dataset. É só fazer uma iteracao nele como eu fiz para imprimir as linhas.

Comment: Seguindo seu conselho eu fiz isto,
+ meu deu erro:TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

tip_amount_total = 0
tip_amount_quantidade = 0
for row in arquivo:
    tip_amount_total += l.split(",")[15] #aqui  somar o decimo quinto item da linha, somar a um valor total
    tip_amount_quantidade += 1 # incrementa a quantidade de tip_amount, basicamente um contador

media_tip_amount = tip_amount_total/tip_amount_quantidade

Comment: Eu ainda estou engatinhando com programação. Então vou nas tentativas e erros. :)

Comment: Melhor tentar aprender do jeito certo, a primeira coisa é tentar interpretar as mensagens de erro, depois tente usar as vantagens do python, uma delas é q vc pode "printar" as variaveis (e seus tipos) no meio do codigo.  A tentativa e erro é muito valida na programação, desde que vc, primeiro, saiba qual é a origiem do erro e o signficado da mensagem.